# How to create infinite scroll in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have an array of response that came from the server with pagination. I want whenever a user scrolls down for more result the next page data should be loaded. Until user did not scroll down the data came from only page 1 and when user scroll down the page should be changed as 2,3,4,.. so on.
can anyone help me to create infinite scroll in angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer my sample, what I apply for table

Html code :

```
<div ng-controller="appController">

    <h1>This is my {{title}} Items: {{numberToDisplay}}/{{totalDisplay}}</h1>
    <div class="constrained">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="loggingTable" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-container='".constrained"' infinite-scroll-distance="1" infinite-scroll-parent="true">
            <tr data-ng-show="logEventFilter.length === 0">
                <td class="center" colspan="3">Nobody is here</td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="logEvent in logEventFilter = (logEvents | limitTo:numberToDisplay) track by $index">
                <td> {{$index}} </td>
                <td> {{logEvent.name}} </td>
                <td> {{numberToDisplay}} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Angularjs code :

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ['infinite-scroll'])
       .controller('appController', appController);

   appController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];

   function appController($scope, $window) {

       $scope.title = "infinite scroll example";
       $scope.numberToDisplay = 20;
                $scope.totalDisplay = 500;
       $scope.logEvents = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalDisplay; i++) {
           $scope.logEvents.push({
               name: "Hello, my name is " + i
           });
       }

       $scope.loadMore = function() {
           if ($scope.numberToDisplay + 5 < $scope.logEvents.length) {
               $scope.numberToDisplay += 5;
           } else {
               $scope.numberToDisplay = $scope.logEvents.length;
           }
       };
   };
```

[sample scroll infinite](https://jsfiddle.net/ptdung0312/dL4fqs81/2/)

Comment: Thanks @thanhdung0312 for the help

Comment: I tried the same solution but getting this error 'infinite-scroll is not available'

Answer (score 1):

you can you [angular ui scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll)

This helps in loading the data as and when the user scrolls down.

Comment: As I told I have multiple page data in different page number, when scroll to bottom then one by one each page number (API) is getting hit. How can I achieve this in angular ui scroll?

Comment: Speaking of ui-scroll, page-based API is being discussed [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/issues/58). Also, [here is the working demo](https://dhilt.github.io/ngx-ui-scroll/#/datasource#pages) for next Angular version (the logic is absolutely relevant to angular-ui-scroll approach).